# How to import OpenAdaptor in an Eclipse project?

Tags: java, eclipse, project, adaptor

I would like to investigate OpenAdaptor. I found class

```
org.openadaptor.spring.SpringAdaptor
```

that has main method. But eclipse doesn't understand it  and display message - cannot find main.
Does it import not correct (imported from file system) or need change something?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what you've done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should be pretty easy to launch adaptors from within eclipse. SpringAdaptor is the correct class.

Create a new Run Configuration from within Eclipse

(main tab)
Set your main class to org.openadaptor.spring.SpringAdaptor
(config tab)

supply the name of the adaptor config(s) you want
-config xml-reader.xml

(your classpath should include the openadaptor libs (e.g. something ike
openadaptor.jar,openadaptor-spring.jar,openadaptor-depends.jar)... In my case I reference the openadaptor classes from within eclipse  as I work with the code directly so my classpath is slightly different.

I hope this is of use.
Regards
Eddy  (I'm one of the developers of openadaptor)